# Graph disappears when using \filldraw

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing a parabola. The LaTeX code works well. However, when I want to have a dot with the code

```
\filldraw (A) circle (1pt) node[above right] {A};
```

then the graph disappears. The code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\a{1}
        \def\c{1}
        \def\xo{1}

        \def\xA{-7}
        \def\xB{2}
        \def\xC{7.5}

        \draw[domain=-2:4,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{\a*(\x-\xo)*(\x-\xo) + \c});

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yA}{\a*(\xA-\xo)*(\xA-\xo)+\c};
        \coordinate (A) at (\xA,\yA);

        \filldraw (A) circle (1pt) node[above right] {A};

        \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (8,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your point A does not seem to be within the graph. Where did you intent to place it?

Comment: it seem as you point out. Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to add a point at `(-7/65)` which is miles away from your graph and thus made the whole image so big that it did not fit on the page.

Your code works fine if one uses a point within the graph instead:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
        
        \def\a{1}
        \def\c{1}
        \def\xo{1}
        
        \def\xA{0} 
        \def\xB{2}
        \def\xC{7.5} 
        
        \draw[domain=-2:4,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{\a*(\x-\xo)*(\x-\xo) + \c}); 
        
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yA}{\a*(\xA-\xo)*(\xA-\xo)+\c}; 
        \coordinate (A) at (\xA,\yA);  
        
        \filldraw (A) circle (1pt) node[above right] {A}; 
    
        \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (8,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Are we able to scale the whole graph to fix on the page?

Comment: @cuongxu sure, `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]`

Comment: thanks. I got it.

Comment: @cuongxu If you would use `pgfplots` instead of directly plotting your curve in tikz, it would automatically scale the image, draw the axis etc.